# Visual Studio 2008 embedded manifest: causes a false alam with Avast! antivirus software

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

The virus scanner "Avast!" is making a false alarm if I embed the manifest in my program.

But I have learned before that without the embedded manifest it will not work for some people (for some reasons I have already forgotten).

So what can I do to make my program work with embedded manifest?

Comment: Avast is not suitable for usage on a programmer's machine, you'll have to get rid of it.

Comment: @HansPassant, but if i compile it successfully, someone with Avast! will still make false alarm from the executable, right? I dont really want to change my antivirus software, Avast! is the best at the moment. And its free too.

Comment: Avast just gets its underwear in a bundle when it sees an EXE file appear from nowhere.  And then gives you a wedgie by locking the file, preventing mt.exe from embedding the manifest.  As long as your own program doesn't create executable files, you'll have little to fear from that shrink-wrapped piece of malware.

Comment: @HansPassant, could it be possible to tell Avast! to not be afraid from my Visual Studio 2008 generated exe files? Was the embedded manifest used for multithreading executables? (one of my program is built as MT, and i use embedded manifest for a reason in it, reason which i forgot..).